# Searching a huge social Database

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am working on implementing search in my Social Networking website and I have this problem.

Say, User "A" is searching for "John" and if that user is a friend of User "A" or friend of friends or friend of friend of friend... recursion level goes till 100, I will be able to find it with search.

What if User "A" has just signed up and has no friends and he is searching for "John" and I have no proper info I can use to filter records? I will have to search my entire database for "John" (ofcourse I am limiting the total search result to 5 using MySQL LIMIT clause).

Is this method efficient or is there anything else I can do to avoid this problem?

And also, First Name, Middle Name, Last Name cannot be set as index since they are not unique. So, I am searching a non-indexed column (without preindexing (Google does preindexing I think) ) and I am using MySQL LIKE for this. So, what should I do about it when considering improving performance?

Using MySQL, PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: You realise that you can have indexes on columns that aren't unique? So just create indexes on those columns... And the only problem with indexing using LIKE is if you search on `%name%` rather than `name%`

Comment: `"is there anything else I can do to avoid this problem?"` - How you would logically filter your records entirely depends on the logic of your social network.  If you have literally *no* data about this user by which to filter potential records, then you don't have any filters to apply.  There's no technical approach which can change the fact that you don't have any data about that user.

Comment: Searching the entire database is actually much simpler and more efficient that traversing paths through 100 levels.

Comment: @MarkBaker: I just came to know that indexed columns need not be unique. Thanks. So, will the search be effective if I index those columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: But if I traverse levels, I dont have to search the entire database right? But maybe, you are right.

Comment: @vignesh: You can perform the *search* on the entire table and then logically sort the results based on connections between users.

Comment: @David: But what if sites like Facebook want to do this? Is it affordable to search the billions of users they have?

Comment: @Vignesh . . . Sites like Facbook are not using MySQL for this purpose.  If you need such deep graph walking capabilities, you may want to consider a database that has efficient support for graph structures (relational databases are often "good enough", but there are better alternatives).  Questions on which database is best would go on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: 100 levels of recursion? Your result will probably a list of each and every other user, if this theory is true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation

Comment: "Facbook are not using MySQL for this purpose" - Are you sure? Cause they store everything in MySQL DBs. They have to ultimately search using MySQL. Or can you use some other software to search a MySQL DB without giving SQL queries?

Comment: @maxhb: Amazing info.. I will limit my recursion level to 6 then.. I did not know about this..

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the problems I see with what you are doing..

By using limit 5 on your Query you are always going to show the first or last 5 John's that the query finds (based on the query).. I would request new users to add their 1st few friends by email (which is unique) or first and last name (non unique)

once the new user has multiple friends you will be able to provide better search results and will be able to avoid always showing the same people to everyone who uses the same keyword/name

Comment: `"you are always going to show the first 5 John's that sign up to you database"` - Or at least the top 5 in some sort order that hasn't been specified.

Comment: Yes, but it might not be the order in which they "sign up to the database".  It would be the first 5 in whatever sort order is requested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem would be that you cannot force a user to add their first few friends by mail. It is optional. So, if they don't then I think I have to search my entire table

Comment: Do you request any information from the users to create a profile.. Maybe City, State, Zip, School, etc..  You can always group people by where  they are located and recommend them users with the same parameters "People you may know"...

Comment: @YacoZaragoza: Yes I do. But again those are optional fields during signup which they can fill up anytime. The only mandatory fields I have is their desired Username, Email ID, Password, First & Last name, Date of birth.